# Фильтрация(удаление) из текстового файла Java

Tags: java, файлы, java-stream

Не получается удалить "нужные" строки из текстового файла. Есть класс модели Person, поля которого парсятся в командной строке и, при помощи команды add добавляются в текстовый файл. Затем, содержимое файла можно посмотреть, введя команду view. А для удаления - используется команда remove. Для этой команды написал следующую логику:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))){
        while ((reader.readLine()) != null){
            people.add(person);
        }
        List<Person> filteredList = people.stream().filter(p -> person.getSurname().equals(searchString)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        people.removeAll(filteredList);
        writer.write(person.getName()+ "\r" + person.getSurname() + "\r" + person.getAge() + "\r" + person.getEmail() + "\r\n\r\n");
    } catch (IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Но, вместо того, чтобы удалить то, что нужно, - удаляется все остальное, а то, что собирался удалить - перезаписывается в файл. Помогите понять, что я делаю не так?

Добавлю немного информации:
Класс модели:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3763710615439958865L;

private static AtomicInteger nextID = new AtomicInteger(0);

private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;
private String email;

private Person(int id, String name, String surname, int age, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
}

public Person(String name, String surname, int age, String email) {
    this(nextID.getAndIncrement(), name, surname, age, email);
}

private int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public static PersonBuilder newBuilder() {
    return new PersonBuilder();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n\nID: " + getId() + "\nName: " + getName() + "\nSurname: " + getSurname() + "\nAge: " + getAge() + "\nE_mail: " + getEmail();
}}
```

Один из классов пакета Контроллера, где реализуется логика для команда "remove":

```
public class DeleteCommand implements Command {
private String fileName;
private String searchString;
private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
private Person person;

public DeleteCommand(String fileName, String searchString, Person person) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.searchString = searchString;
    this.person = person;
}

@Override
public void execute(String[] args) {
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))){
        while ((reader.readLine()) != null){
            people.add(person);
        }
        List<Person> filteredList = people.stream().filter(p -> p.getSurname().equals(searchString)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        people.removeAll(filteredList);

        writer.write(person.getName()+ "\r" + pperson.getSurname() + "\r" + person.getAge() + "\r" + person.getEmail() + "\r\n\r\n");

    } catch (IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }}}
```

Comment: если это реальный код, то он странный. Вы добавляете в список `people` ссылки на некий объект `person` по числу строк в входном файле, затем производите с этим списком какие-то манипуляции, затем пишете данные из объекта `person` в выходной файл и на этом заканчиваете (список в записи вообще не участвует).

Comment: Ну,people, в данном случае, это не список, а коллекция List<Person> people. Т.е. просто переназначается исходная ссылка на отфильтрованную коллекцию (т.е. people = filteredList). Во всяком случае, я так понимаю. Но, если я что-то понимаю неправильно, - подскажите, как правильно. Я могу разместить больше кода, чтобы стало яснее, если нужно.

Comment: в выходном файле оказывается только объект который вы хотели удалить (`person`), потому что строка `writer.write(person.getName()...` его туда пишет и это единственная строка, которая пишет в файл. С чтением тоже все плохо, т.к. вы просто игнорируете прочитанные из файла строки. Фильтрацию можно было бы заменить на `removeIf`, но она рабочая.

Comment: ок, попробую с removeif...

Comment: @zRrr - ну, с removeif ситуация такая же... Видимо я на чем-то все время спотыкаюсь, а где - не вижу. Если можете как-то более подробно показать, буду крайне признателен.

Comment: вы не сохраняете ваш список в файл

Comment: по коду совсем не понятно откуда берется person и почему он сохраняется ?!

Comment: @keekkenen Я добавил код, может быть так понятнее будет, откуда взялся "person"...

Answer (score 1):

Если ориентироваться на описанные вами симптомы, то очевидно, надо обратить условие предиката

```
.filter(p -> !p.getSurname().equals(searchString)).
```

Но судя по коду, описанного происходить вообще не может. Неважно, что и как вы фильтруете, если потом не используете результат фильтрации. Вместо записи в файл списка `people` вы записываете данные `person`.

Примерно так можно реализовать вашу задачу:

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
    private int age;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public static Person valueOf(String[] fields) {
        Person person = new Person(fields[0], fields[1]);
        person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));
        person.setEmail(fields[3]);
        return person;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s", name, surname, age, email);
    }
}

class DeleteCommand implements Command {
    private final String fileName;
    private final Predicate<Person> condition;

    public DeleteCommand(String fileName, Predicate<Person> condition) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            Path tmp = Files.createTempFile(fileName, ".tmp");
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(tmp.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())) {

                stream.map(s -> s.split("\t"))
                      .map(Person::valueOf)
                      .filter(condition)
                      .forEachOrdered(pw::println);
            }
            Files.copy(tmp, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String searchString = "Doe";
        Predicate<Person> predicate = p -> p.getSurname().equals(searchString);
        Command command = new DeleteCommand("people.csv", predicate.negate());
        command.execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но, к сожалению, даже после изменения - результат тот же. И от этого еще непонятнее, что не так...

Comment: код понятнее не стал.. `people.add(person);` почему всегда один и тот же `person` добавляется и как он связан с тем, что в файле находится ?